# Contracts with custom fee and limited numbers of transactions

Tags: contract-development

Is there a valid way to set custom re-sell fee for "custom currency", e.g. https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/12/03/how-to-build-your-own-cryptocurrency/ and limit this re-sells somehow?
For example:
0. custom currency can contain $ value, and its can be different (like different kinds of same contract)

1. first transaction A => B (0% custom fee, just ethereum network fee)
2. B => C (10% custom fee in ETH + ethereum network fee)
3. C => X -- transaction not allowed.
4. Also it is possible to to save custom fee in dollar (int) values in second step?( how i will proceed this fee its my headache)

Apologies for so many random questions, any hints are appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a token contract with custom logic. You would need to store the number of transactions associated with a given token and charge accordingly. Storage cost might become really expensive though.

The code for token contracts can be found here with explanations:
https://ethereum.org/token (This is the one used in the blog post you've linked.)

You cannot use that token contract as is, but probably helps to understand the basic concepts around it.